# GET http://localhost:8100/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm displaying an image, `<img [src]="anImage">`, after converting it, and some time I'm getting this error message, **but not always**.

[image]

I think it's because the process to convert the image takes time. I have to say too, even with this error the image is displayed.

**anImage looks like this:**

[image]

Someone know how to resolved this error ?

Comment: It's normal, do a console.log in your object. Your object it's not a string, you gonna get something like this 'myobject.link'

Comment: I've edit the post to show you how it looks

Comment: Show me your error message after the <img [src]="anImage.name">

Answer (score 0):

So your solution is :

`<img *ngIf="anImage" [src]="anImage.name">`

I've edited my response

Comment: That would require the image to exist at `http://localhost:8100/photo1.jpg`, but there's no reason to suspect that. This looks like a file selected by the user using a file `<input>`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The image is display but i get sometime an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the conversion from input image and it works without problem. The conversion was generating sometime this error. It came from a object set to any instead of string.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

This error occur from an internal error, a data you enter or use must be from another type.

I had the same issue, when I use a object that didn't have a method I use.